# Updating data in mySQL database using JTable in netbeans with mouse click event

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I am writing a code in netbeans wherein when clicked on a specific row the data is automatically updated from 'N' to 'Y' in mySQL  database.
I have written the following code. Please see if there's anything wrong with it.
Tried using debugger, but it is not even going inside the click count loop.

```
private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    if(evt.getClickCount()==2){

        int getsel = jTable2.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int value = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(getsel, 6).toString());
        try{

            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from roomservice where guestid = "+value);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                String taskstatus = rs.getString("taskstatus");
                if(taskstatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){

                    ps = con.prepareStatement("update roomservice set taskstatus = 'N' where guestid= "+value);
                    ps.executeUpdate();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "updated task status");

                }else if(taskstatus.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("update roomservice set taskstatus = 'Y' where guestid= "+value);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "updated task status");
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
  }
```

[image: Here is mySql database description]

Comment: Before your `if` statement do `System.out.println ("" + evt.getClickCount());`

Comment: It shows 1, when in fact i am clicking twice. @ScaryWombat

Comment: Add on an Answer so I can vote for it.
It worked perfectly! @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html

clicking twice does not make the click count two - try press mouse button one , press mouse button two, then release buttons